Why can we convert a power series of operators to a function, invert the function, and then work with its series expansion?
I apologize as I am still somewhat unfamiliar with infinite series and knowing when and how we are allowed to use them, and especially with working with operators in this way. I imagine that I will be incorrect somewhere in this post or in its title.
I am working with finite-difference schemes for derivatives. I was reading a thesis on the subject when I came across the following material from the appendix of the book Numerical Analysis by Zdenek Kopal.
Suppose $\phi$ is a function of a single variable, $x$, which is discretized into a mesh $x_i = x_0 + ih$ defined by a spacing parameter $h$. We will use the notation $\phi(x + ih) = \phi(x_i) = \phi_i$. Note that this will be the case even for cases when $i$ is not an integer and therefore $x_i$ does not lie on the mesh.
Note that, by Taylor expansion,
$$\begin{equation}
\phi_{i+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{h^n}{n!}\phi^{(n)}_i = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(h\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x})^n}{n!}\phi_i = e^{h\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}}\phi_i.
\end{equation}\label{1}\tag{1}$$
Define an operator $\delta$ such that $\delta\phi_i = \phi_{i + \frac12} - \phi_{i - \frac12}$. Per the above Taylor expansion, we have
$$\begin{equation}
\delta\phi_i = (e^{\frac{h}{2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}} - e^{-\frac{h}{2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}})\phi_i,
\end{equation}\label{2}\tag{2}$$
so
$$\begin{equation}\frac{\delta}{2} = \sinh\left(\frac h2 \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\right).
\end{equation}\label{3}\tag{3}$$
Therefore we can write
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} = \frac{2}{h}\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)
\end{equation}\label{4}\tag{4}$$
and especially (using the series expansion of arcsinh)
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} = \frac2h\left[\frac\delta2 - \left(\frac12\right)\frac{\delta^3}{2^3\cdot3} + \left({1 \cdot 3 \over 2 \cdot 4}\right)\frac{\delta^5}{2^5\cdot5}- \left({1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \over 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6}\right)\frac{\delta^7}{2^7\cdot7} + \dots\right].
\end{equation}\label{5}\tag{5}$$
I am comfortable with \eqref{1} with the caveat that I don't understand why we are allowed to use all the infinite number of terms in the first step and expect equality. I am fully comfortable with both \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} as, in my mind, functions with operators as inputs are just shorthand for the full infinite series.
However, I see no reason why we should be able to deduce \eqref{4} and \eqref{5}. Why should we be able to transition from infinite series to function to inverse function back to infinite series and know that our result is correct? Another point of confusion for me is that since operators are not numbers, how would we even describe convergence of an infinite series of them? The radius of convergence of the series expansion of arcsinh (when defined with numbers) is finite, but is that of concern? How can I better understand what's going on here?
Later statements in the thesis involve a series expansion of $\left(1 + \frac{\delta^2}{4}\right)^{-\frac{1}2}$ and division by $\delta$ and another operator which I will not define here. I find these things to be just as confusing as what I have described above.
I realize I ask a lot of questions, but any amount of information regarding this, pointers to resources, or even the name of a topic I can research to learn about this would be immensely helpful to me.

I don't understand the question you raise with (1)... What would be strange would be to not consider all the terms and still expect equality. If fact, if $\phi$ is analytic,
$$ \phi_{i+1} = \phi(x_i+h) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\phi^{(n)}(x_i)}{n!} h^n$$
The remaining equalities in (1) are purely symbolic and are just relevant to understand why such an operator would be denoted by $e^{h \frac{d}{dx}}$.
Expression (4) is obtained just by solving (3) with respect to $\frac{d}{dx}$.

You're correct about (1), we do need all terms to have equality. My only question regarding that is how we know when Taylor series converge, but maybe that has to be proven on a case by case basis?

I can follow the steps for getting (4) from (3), I just wonder why we are allowed to invert sinh if it's just placeholder notation for a series. It feels naïve, but again, I'm new to this. If it's an obvious result, what makes it obvious? Is there a text I can consult or a subject I can learn? Is there a deeper reason why it's allowed? Furthermore, why can we take the series expansion of arcsinh? What is a "local" expansion when the inputs are operators? Would there be a scenario for a different function with an operator input where we couldn't expand it?

It is possible to provide a rigorous foundation for the statement that the forward shift operator is isometrically equivalent to $\exp( \frac{d}{dx})$. The answer hinges on properties of the smooth Fourier transform from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ into itself. I do not see a good way to resolve the issue related to the unsupported application of the Taylor expansion of the function arcsinh. Moving forward, I propose that you comment on the only answer that you have received at this point.

Answer
This is simply the operational calculus, or better the calculus of pseudodifferential operators, in disguise and the transformations and operations on the operators involved are simply to be understood as the same transformations and operations applied to their symbols.
The rational basis of the answer
Let's implicitly assume that $\phi$ is a Fourier transformable (possibly generalized) function (for example let it be a slowly increasing distribution $\phi\in\mathscr S^\prime(\Bbb R))$ in order to justify the formal operations show below.
Then
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{d}\DeclareMathOperator{\imu}{\mathscr{i}\!}
\begin{split}
\hat\phi(\xi) &=\int\limits_{\Bbb R} e^{-\mathscr{i}\langle x,\xi\rangle}\phi(x) \Dm\! x\\
\phi(x) &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{\Bbb R} e^{\mathscr{i}\langle x,\xi\rangle}\hat\phi(\xi)\Dm\! \xi
\end{split}
$$ are the direct and inverse Fourier transforms (I used $\imu\triangleq\sqrt{-1}$) in order to avoid confusion with the finite differences index $i$). Now we can easily see that, for a given finite order linear constant coefficients (ordinary) differential operator $P\left(\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right)= a_0+ a_1 \frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}+a_2\frac{\Dm^2}{\Dm\! x^2} + \ldots a_m \frac{\Dm^m}{\Dm\! x^m}=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k\frac{\Dm^k}{\Dm\! x^k}$ we have the following equality
$$
P\left(\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right)\phi(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{\Bbb R} e^{\mathscr{i}\langle x,\xi\rangle}P\left(\imu \xi\right)\hat\phi(\xi)\Dm\! \xi\label{6}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
thus we have a one-to-one pairing between the operator polynomial $P\left(\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right)$ and the polynomial $P\left(\imu\xi\right)$: the polynomial is then called the "symbol of the operator".
We can formally extend this pairing to any analytic function, say for example
$$
\begin{split}
f\left(h\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right) &\triangleq\exp\left(h\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right) = e^{h\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}}\\
\frac{\delta}{2}\left(h\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right) &\triangleq \sinh\left(\frac h2\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right)
\end{split}
$$
thus getting
$$
\begin{split}
f\left(h\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right) &\mapsto\exp\left(\imu h\xi\right) = e^{\imu h\xi}\\
\frac{\delta}{2}\left(h\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right) &\mapsto \frac{\delta}{2}\left(\imu h\xi\right) \triangleq \sinh\left(\imu \frac{h\xi}{2}\right).
\end{split}
$$
Now we are done: for example equations \eqref{4} and \eqref{5} are simply obtained by inversion and approximation by its Taylor polynomial of the symbol. Precisely
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}
\frac{\delta}{2}\left(h\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}\right) \mapsto  \sinh\left(\imu \frac{h\xi}{2}\right)\iff \imu\xi = \frac{2}{h}\arcsinh\left(\sinh\left(\imu \frac{h\xi}{2}\right)\right) \mapsto \frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}
$$
and
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}
\begin{split}
\imu\xi & = \frac{2}{h}\arcsinh\left(\sinh\left(\imu \frac{h\xi}{2}\right)\right)  \\
& = \frac2h\left[\sinh\left(\imu \frac{h\xi}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2\cdot3}\right)\sinh\left(\imu \frac{h\xi}{2}\right)^3 + \left({1 \cdot 3 \over 2 \cdot 4\cdot 5}\right)\sinh\left(\imu \frac{h\xi}{2}\right)^5 + \dots\right] \\ \\
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\Updownarrow\\ \\
\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x} & =  \frac2h\left[\frac\delta2 - \left(\frac12\right)\frac{\delta^3}{2^3\cdot3} + \left({1 \cdot 3 \over 2 \cdot 4}\right)\frac{\delta^5}{2^5\cdot5}- \left({1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \over 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6}\right)\frac{\delta^7}{2^7\cdot7} + \dots\right]
\end{split}
$$
Notes

Strictly speaking the above development can be made perfectly rigorous only on the space of Fourier hyperfunctions $\mathscr{FB}(\Bbb R)$, as only these generalized functions can accept all real analytic functions $\mathscr{A}(\Bbb R)$ as Fourier multipliers (loosely speaking, this means that \eqref{6} is well defined for any $f(x)\in \mathscr{A}(\Bbb R)$). Technically operators obtained from real analytic functions are called constant coefficients infinite order linear differential operators.
Why there is no mentions in books on the calculus of finite differences of the above developments? Because the calculus of finite differences, the calculus of infinite order operators, was developed along these (formal) lines long before of the calculus of pseudodifferential operators: indeed the latter one can be possibly seen as a tentative to make this and Heaviside's operational calculus rigorous. After all, these calculi can be developed from the standard one by simply assuming that $\frac{\Dm}{\Dm\! x}$ is a real (or complex) variable: and that was precisely done by Oliver Heaviside, Salvatore Pincherle, and Joseph Fells Ritt just to name a few.


How can we justify writing $z = \text{arcsinh}(\sinh(z))$ for $z$ on the imaginary axis when $\sinh(k\pi i) = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?
